# Converting video using php

Tags: php

We can convert video file to .flv format by ffmpeg-php extension but how can we convert .flv to other format, i searched but no solution find...

```
//ececute ffmpeg generate flv
  exec('ffmpeg -i '.$uploadfile.' -f flv -s 320x240 '.$new_flv.'');

// But can we this, convert it to mpeg..
  exec('ffmpeg -i '.$uploadfile.' -f mpg -s 320x240 '.$new_flv.'');

//execute ffmpeg and create thumb
  exec('ffmpeg  -i '.$uploadfile.' -f mjpeg -vframes 1 -s 150x150 -an '.$new_image_path.'');
```

Or, is there any php api like (ffmpeg) to do this....???

Comment: ffmpeg is best. Try posting this question on ffmpeg forums. exec will run your command. Just worry about getting ffmpeg right. Is it running from terminal ?

Comment: here i want just suggestion, if any body know alternate way......

Answer (score 1):

the response is in the [documentation](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) but here are some [command examples](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/19-ffmpeg-commands-for-all-needs) that i find quite useful

Good Luck

Comment: `ffmpeg -i video_origine.flv video_finale.avi`

Comment: yes, i also find some commands to convert flv to mpeg format,            Ffmpeg -i video.flv -ab 56 -ar 22050 -b 500 -s 320×240 video.mpg              thanks.