# different video format supported by html and major browsers

Tags: php, video, upload, ffmpeg

hello all i am building a video hosting site and wanted to know what are the video formats which my php code should convert the user's video so that all the major browsers support the file.

by searching on internet i got to know that mp4,swf,avi,ogg are the formats but if i convert one video to all these formats then there will be 4 times the space of a single video and also there will be server load and time consuming process for the conversion.

so i was wondering if there is one or two formats which i should take with me so to reduce the server load and conversion time.

i am converting the video by this code (ffmpeg)

```
 if (move_uploaded_file(@$_FILES['profileimage99']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {

    $base = basename($uploadfile, $safe_file['ext']);
    $new_file = $base.'flv';
    $new_image = $base.'jpg';
    $new_image_path = $live_img.$new_image;
    $new_flv = $live_dir.$new_file;

        require 'vendor/autoload.php';
        //ececute ffmpeg generate flv
        exec('ffmpeg -i '.$uploadfile.' -f flv -s 768x432 '.$new_flv.'');
        //execute ffmpeg and create thumb
        exec('ffmpeg  -i '.$uploadfile.' -f mjpeg -vframes 71 -s 768x432 -an '.$new_image_path.'');
```

also please tell me will it be good to use exec in php code ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common web video formats are WebM, OGG, and MP4 with MP4 being supported in IE, Chrome, Safari, Opera, and FireFox.

Therefore, it would be prudent to stick with MP4.

Comment: what do you think about swf

Comment: I think it doesn't run natively in browsers and anything that requires plugins to run isn't best practice.

Comment: ok thankyou sir, can you also tell me is it good practice to convert the video by exec command in php i am using ffmpeg .... and is there any other alternative way to convert the video so as to reduce time and load

Comment: Can't help you there I'm afraid, I'm not that familiar with PHP but there is an existing question for video conversion in PHP [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975034/converting-video-using-php).

Comment: ok thnkx for your reply... :) i will keep this question open for some time to ger some reply for php_ffmpeg

Comment: You can use mp4 for major compatible latest browser now mp4 has widely compatible for every browser check here http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp